# React App is not loading on nginx on Debian VM

Tags: reactjs, nginx, debian

I'm trying to deploy a React Web App on a Debian VM using nginx.

My root points to the build folder in my git repo `(/home/myuser/Projects/mysite/build)`. This way I can update my app by git pull whenever I make a change.

I have created a conf file in /etc/nginx/conf.d/react.conf, and it looks like:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /home/myuser/Projects/mysite/build;
        index index.html index.htm;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/siteoneway.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/siteoneway.error.log;


        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

In `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, I comment this line (`include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*`):

```
##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    # include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

So, when I access http://mypublicIP, the browser just shows a blank white screen. If I press F12, I see content of index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
      <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>
      <meta name="description" content="My Site Name"/>
      <title>My Site Name</title>
      <link rel="icon" href="/favicon/favicon-32x32.png"/>
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/favicon/android-chrome-192x192.png"/>
      <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>
      <script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.cd92e2ed.js"></script>
      <link href="/static/css/main.5b13449a.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
      <div id="root"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

, but the site is not opening.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours, I found the error. There was an error  setting on package.json, the "homepage" property was filled with an incorrect value.